# Condicional no funciona en JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Les comento, soy nuevo en html y estuve practicando un poco con JavaScript. ""Cree"" un código que calcula tu peso según la gravedad de diferentes planetas. La cosa es que en la ultima condicional, que debería verificar que si no elegiste 1 o 2 (Marte o Jupiter) imprima en el documento "Eleji un planeta valido". Lo probé pero en vez de imprimir eso, sale esto: "Tu peso en undefined es de NaNkg"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tu peso en otro planeta.</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Tu peso en otros planetas :)</h1>
        <script>
            var g_tierra = 9.8;
            var g_marte = 3.7;
            var g_jupiter = 24.8;

            var usuario = parseInt(prompt("Cual es tu peso?"));
            var planeta = parseInt(prompt("Elije un planeta\n 1 es Marte, 2 es Jupiter."));
            var planeta_elejido;     

            if (planeta == 1)
            {
                peso_final = usuario * g_marte / g_tierra;
                planeta_elejido = "Marte"
            }
            else if (planeta == 2)
            {
                peso_final = usuario * g_jupiter / g_tierra;
                planeta_elejido = "Jupiter"
            }
           
            var peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);

            if (planeta == 1 || 2)
            {
                document.write("Tu peso en " + planeta_elejido + " es de " + peso_final + "<b>kg</b>");
            }
            else
            {
                document.write("Eleji un planeta valido.")
            }
             
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La condición `if (planeta == 1 || 2)` siempre es cierta porque estas haciendo mal el `if`.

La condición se evalúa a `true` porque al hacer una condición `or` si el primer valor(`planeta == 1`) es `false` se evalua el segundo y en tu caso siempre es cierto porque es un `2` "truthy" porque es distinto a `false, null, undefined, 0, ""` que son valores "falsy".

Tienes que hacerlo así.

```
if (planeta == 1 || planeta == 2) {}
```